# How to set jvm heap size when starting a jade agent

Tags: java, out-of-memory, jvm-arguments, agents-jade

I'm trying to increase jvm heap size because my JADE agent program throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error.

I have set java heap size using *Java Control Panel -> Java Runtime Environment Settings* in Windows 7. But it doesn't help. How can I set `-Xmx` for jade agent?

Answer (score 0):

I have same the problem when run Jade with many sending and receiving messages between agents.

The problem maybe is since A sends messages very fast while B extracts them from its queue VERY slow (he sleeps for 3 secs after each message), the queue of B becomes bigger and bigger until the heap of the JVM is full.

You can limit the size of the message queue of an agent by means of the setQueueSize() method of the Agent class.

Please read it to know in more details:

http://avalon.tilab.com/pipermail/jade-develop/2008q3/012893.html